# Apply Row_Number for 3 columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I've a table named as "Temp" like this,

```
ItemId  JobId   Status
1       11      Yes
1       12      No
1       12      Yes
1       13      Yes
2       12      Yes
2       12      Yes
2       11      No
2       13      Yes
2       13      No
2       13      Yes
```

My expected output is, Needs to set series for these 3 columns(ItemId, JobId, Status) based on values.

Output should be as,

```
iID     iSN     JobId   JobSN   Status  statusId
1       1       11      1       Yes     1
1       2       12      1       No      1
1       3       12      2       Yes     1
1       4       13      1       Yes     1
2       1       12      1       Yes     1
2       2       12      2       Yes     2
2       3       11      1       No      1
2       4       13      1       Yes     1
2       5       13      2       No      1
2       6       13      3       Yes     2

Here iSN needs to set based on ItemId
JobSN based on JobId->ItemId
StatusId based on Status->JobId->ItemId
```

I know to set the series on a column, need to partition over the column by using **ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION [ColumnName])...**

But, how can i apply for get expected output. Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You result makes little sense. Please describe how the output relates to input.

Comment: It seems like you already know what to do, what is the problem here?

Comment: Do you have any column that can be used for the order by clause?

Comment: I am getting a feeling that you don't know that in Relational databases, a table is an unordered set of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a column that you can use to sort the rows by, you can do something like this:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    ItemId int,
    JobId int,
    [Status] varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 11, 'Yes'),
(1, 12, 'No'),
(1, 12, 'Yes'),
(1, 13, 'Yes'),
(2, 12, 'Yes'),
(2, 12, 'Yes'),
(2, 11, 'No'),
(2, 13, 'Yes'),
(2, 13, 'No'),
(2, 13, 'Yes')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  ItemId As iID,     
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY id) As iSN,
        JobId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobId, ItemId ORDER BY id) As JobSN,
        [Status],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Status],JobId, ItemId ORDER BY id) As statusId
FROM @T
ORDER BY id
```

Results:

```
iID     iSN     JobId   JobSN   Status  statusId
1       1       11      1       Yes     1
1       2       12      1       No      1
1       3       12      2       Yes     1
1       4       13      1       Yes     1
2       1       12      1       Yes     1
2       2       12      2       Yes     2
2       3       11      1       No      1
2       4       13      1       Yes     1
2       5       13      2       No      1
2       6       13      3       Yes     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the statusId column is not clear to me. Hope this can be a start.

```
SELECT ItemId
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY ItemID) AS iSN
    , JobId
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobId, ItemID ORDER BY ItemId) AS iSN
    , Status
FROM @T 
ORDER BY ItemId
```

Result

```
+------+----+------+----+-------+
|ItemId|iSN |JobId |iSN |Status |
+------+----+------+----+-------+
|1     |1   |11    |1   |Yes
|1     |2   |12    |1   |No
|1     |3   |12    |2   |Yes
|1     |4   |13    |1   |Yes
|2     |1   |11    |1   |No
|2     |2   |12    |1   |Yes
|2     |3   |12    |2   |Yes
|2     |4   |13    |1   |Yes
|2     |5   |13    |2   |No
|2     |6   |13    |3   |Yes
+------+----+------+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Itemid AS iID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID  ORDER BY JobID, STATUS) AS iSN
, JobID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID,JobID  ORDER BY JobID, STATUS) AS iSN
, Status
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID,JobID,STATUS  ORDER BY JobID, STATUS) AS statusid
FROM TEMP;
```

but you have to decide ORDER BY rules to obtain always same results: mine are slightly different from yours)

```
iID         iSN                  JobID       iSN                  Status statusid
----------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- ------ --------------------
1           1                    11          1                    Yes    1
1           2                    12          1                    No     1
1           3                    12          2                    Yes    1
1           4                    13          1                    Yes    1
2           1                    11          1                    No     1
2           2                    12          1                    Yes    1
2           3                    12          2                    Yes    2
2           4                    13          1                    No     1
2           5                    13          2                    Yes    1
2           6                    13          3                    Yes    2
```